# What are some good tips for people who wants to start a workshop from scratch?

Tags: workshop

I, and a group of my colleagues want to start a workshop which covers a topic which generally draws interest but usually categorized as "other topics" in well-known workshops.

We want to start a workshop for such a topic. We are well aware that initial impression of an organization is very important. Thus, we want to avoid some blatant blunders.
What are the best practices for a group of 4-5 people who intend to start a workshop? What kind of advice "save lives" in this context?

Comment: In what context would the workshop be delivered? Is this a workshop for institutional peers, a conference workshop, a student workshop, a webinar, a workshop where you actually build things ...?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin It is a theoretical workshop in the field of computer science which aims to encourage people to share their ongoing work and find collaborators, and ultimately publish some papers out of their efforts in the workshop.

Answer (score 2):

In Computer Science, many successful workshops are attached to major conferences, taking place on the days around the main conference. So (1) attend those workshops and see how they run, what you like or dislike, etc. (2) Submit a workshop proposal to the most relevant conference and trying to get included in the workshop schedule. This makes recruiting participants and the audience much easier --- they are already at the conference anyway.

To host a new workshop not attached to a conference, never having done it before, I'd really recommend adding some organizers with lots of experience -- and it doesn't hurt if their well-known names will entice people to come. (Sorry, that's how it works.)

Other than that, I would frankly say there's nothing tricky about it. I don't think I've ever been to a bad workshop -- not surprising, since I generally sign up because I like the topic! Some tentative suggestions:

- Get at least 1-2 good, well-known invited speakers to give talks (45min plus questions is my suggestion).
- Solicit submissions broadly and select some to give short talks (20-30min including questions is my suggestion). Focus on talks you think will be interesting to the audience, not necessarily the best/strongest work.
- Make one of your goals diversity of your set of speakers.
- A poster session and/or social time can be good. You can accept anything you rejected above as a poster.
- Build in enough breaks and discussion/Q&A, be careful not to overstuff the schedule.
- Speaking of schedule, it's probably good to have a webpage with the schedule and overview. Most of the schedule, like identities of the talks, can stay TBA for a while, it's ok.

There's probably an additional list of tips for a virtual modality....

Comment: This doesn't sound like a workshop, but a special interest sub-conference. Yes, CS conferences have workshops as well as what you describe. If it is a place to "get work done" then you don't need speakers or poster sessions. This seems too passive for most attendees. The Educators track at OOPSLA, for example was like what you describe, but it isn't really a workshop. The Doctoral Symposium is, however, just a workshop for sharing ideas of attendees and getting feedback. Much simpler to organize.

Comment: I don't think a workshop includes posters ...

Comment: That's a good answer but unfortunately does not fully address my question. I'm not asking about a workshop which is attached to a conference. Hence the phrase "from scratch." I myself also never attended to a bad workshop but this doesn't mean that bad workshops don't exist.

Comment: @padawan I don't think "from scratch" implies "not attached to a conference." If that's what you're looking for, you should edit to be a little clearer.

Comment: @BUffy, okay, we call them workshops. For example, if you look at all six workshops attached to STOC 2020, you'll find they are all just sequences of talks. http://acm-stoc.org/stoc2020/STOCprogram.html This theoretical-minded workshop at NeurIPS 2020 is exactly as I describe: https://neurips.cc/Conferences/2020/Schedule?showEvent=16150